# How to get rows from a list containing each couple of value in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of "Couple" with the following structure

```
public class Couple
{
    public string Code;
    public string Label;
}
```

And another list of "Stuff" like that

```
public class Stuff
{
    public string CodeStuff;
    public string LabelStuff;
    public int foo;
    public int bar;
    //etc...
}
```

I want to get all the Stuff objects where each couples *(Code, Label)* in my `List<Couple>` match with *(CodeStuff, Label,Stuff)* from `List<Stuff>`.

For example the Couple

```
Couple c = new Couple { Code = "ABC", Label = "MyLabel1" };
```

will match with  the **first row only** from

```
 Stuff s1 = new { CodeStuff = "ABC", LabelStuff = "MyLabel1" }; // OK
 Stuff s1 = new { CodeStuff = "ABC", LabelStuff = "MyLabel2" }; // NOT OK
 Stuff s1 = new { CodeStuff = "DEF", LabelStuff = "MyLabel1" }; // NOT OK
```

I tried to use `.Where` clause or `.Foreach` but I don't know how to get the couple (Code,Label) together. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use linq join.

```
            List<Couple> lstcouple = new List<Couple>();
            List<Stuff> lstStuff = new List<Stuff>();

            var result = (from s in lstStuff
                          join c in lstcouple on new { CS = s.CodeStuff, LS = s.LabelStuff } equals new { CS = c.Code, LS = c.Label }
                          select s).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a join? might need tweaking, but as an idea:

```
var joined = from c in couplesList
             join s in stuffList on c.Code equals s.CodeStuff
             where c.Label == s.LabelStuff
             select s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Stuff> stuffs = new List<Stuff>{s1,s2,s3};
List<Couple> couples = new List<Couple>{c};

var filteredList = stuffs.
                          Where
                               (x=> couples.Any(y => y.Code == x.CodeStuff)
                                 && couples.Any(y=>  y.Label == x.LabelStuff)
                               ).ToList();
```